# JQuery UI Button/Widget Memory Leak in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, memory-leaks

This simple code appears to cause massive memory leak in IE8 (with and without compatibility view).

I need to automatically refresh a table containing jQuery UI buttons. The memory leak behavior is the same with progress bars. It leaks 1.5 MB every refresh!
sIEve doesn't show leaks, but does show memory usage only increase. Task manager shows climbing memory usage.

Help. What am I not cleaning up on refresh?

Working test: http://jsfiddle.net/QsXGS/

HTML:

```
<div id="leakTest"></div>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    function replaceButtons() {
        $("button").button("destroy");
        $("#leakTest").children().remove();
        $("#leakTest").append("<div>" + new Date() + "</div>");
        for(var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            $("#leakTest").append("<button>Button</button>");
        }
        $("button").button();
    }

    replaceButtons();
    setInterval(replaceButtons, 5000);
});
```